# When should caching variable look-ups in local scope be a must in (cross-browser) JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, caching, cross-browser, scope, lookup

I've mostly thought that the less variables I declare the better off I am. So when I went through [the presentation notes of the talk by Julien Lecomte](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/12/20/video-lecomte/) and found him declaring local variables to reduce look-up overhead..

```
var arr = ...;
var globalVar = 0;
(function () {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        localVar++;
    }
})();

/* vs */

var arr = ...;
var globalVar = 0;
(function () {
    var i, l , localVar;
    l = arr.length;
    localVar = globalVar;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        localVar++;
    }
    globalVar = localVar;
})();

/* (faster on all A-grade browsers) */
```

**Edit**: when designing a JavaScript based webapp/-site to run on all modern desktop and mobile browsers - are there cases when I should always prefer caching variable look-ups in local scope due to the cost of look-ups? (e.g. when accessing more then once an object assigned to `myArray[100][20][40][90]` or changing several properties of an object which lays many levels up the current scope, loops by the thousands?)

Or is the look-up time so irrelevantly small that I would be better off saving character space and memory by leaving out local cache variables?

Comment: There's no one answer to this question, not least because of the wild variations between popular JavaScript engines. Some people believe in always caching `arr.length` to a local. Others consider it premature optimization until/unless there's a specific, real-world, observable issue (and even then, you'd have to prove that it had any real effect as opposed to being swamped by the work you're doing in the actual loop).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I have read Julien's notes and wondered the same thing. He believed he was on to something.

Comment: Narrowed down the question, please let me know if it's still too broad. Is this subject concidered just as a coding style issue?

Answer (score 0):

T.J. Crowder explained it well I think.
It really depends on:

1. "How" you use your array.
2. "How" "big" it is.
3. Is it a plain array, or it an array of arrays of arrays!

For example, if you have an object (which has methods and attributes you need to access frequently) deep down in your array "myArray" like `myArray[100][20][40][90]` and you keep using that object frequently, would be faster if you just cache the object in some variable and use the cached version!

Comment: My question was rather concerned with only the look-up costs, as you can see from the code example, I'm not doing much with the array itself - could you explain the look-up cost part and give a more concrete example to accompany it?

Comment: After reading your comment and reading the question several times, I see no need to use "localVar" at all, why not just increment "globalVar" in the loop? or for better/faster performance, why not just do this before or after the loop: `globalVar += arr.length;`?